# Не могу понять в чём ошибка, что не так?

Tags: python, синтаксис

```
print("Привет!\nТы открыл программу для получения всех возможных комбинаций состоящих из 3 чисел")

K=-1
while K!=0:
    K=input("Ну что, продолжим?\n"
    "1-Продолжить\n"
    "2-Покинуть программу\n"
    "Я не отстану, введи число 1 или 2 и даже не думай нажимать на крестик!\n")
    if K=="1":  
        var_1 = int(input("Введите первое число: "))
        var_2 = int(input("Введите второе число: "))
        var_3 = int(input("Введите третье число: "))
    agregator = []
    agregator.append(var_1)
    agregator.append(var_2)
    agregator.append(var_3)
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            for k in range(0, 3):
                if(i != j & j != k & k != i):
                    print(agregator[i], agregator[j], agregator[k])
                    break
    elif K=="2":
        break
    else:
        print ("Нет-нет, так не пойдёт, давай 1 или 2 :)")
```

Я в программировании не силён, но попытался что-то придумать, взял скелет, но в конечном итоге выдает ошибку, мол не знает, что такое elif K=="2":

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Буду благодарен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В питоне отступы важны, а т.к. начиная с `agregator = []` у вас отступы меньше, чем внутри `if`, то интерпретатор решил, что это не попадает в условие, тогда `elif K=="2":` лишился логической связи с первым `if`

Попробуйте:

```
    if K=="1":  
        var_1 = int(input("Введите первое число: "))
        var_2 = int(input("Введите второе число: "))
        var_3 = int(input("Введите третье число: "))
        agregator = []
        agregator.append(var_1)
        agregator.append(var_2)
        agregator.append(var_3)
        for i in range(0, 3):
            for j in range(0, 3):
                for k in range(0, 3):
                    if (i != j & j != k & k != i):
                        print(agregator[i], agregator[j], agregator[k])
                        break
    elif K=="2":
        break
    else:
        print ("Нет-нет, так не пойдёт, давай 1 или 2 :)")
```

Comment: Всё получилось, благодарю!

Comment: @SanyaNICE, пожалуйста :)